# how to fix shifting after animation in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, animation

I just made a text animation (fade in; animate(top, opacity)) and at the end, the text went about 5px left then returned to its original position, quite quickly. This happened in IE only; all other major browsers behaved normally.

Any idea about why it happens, and how to fix it?  I am interested in fixing IE7 in particular.

Thanks.

(PS, I removed the filter attribute in order to avoid ClearType glitch.)

**HTML**

```
<div id="logomarca">
    <h1 id="marca">txt</h1>
    <p id="spec">txt</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div#logomarca{     
position:absolute;
left:50%;
top:0%;
margin-top:-83px;
margin-left:-83px;
width:160px;
height:45px;
    }
p#spec{position:absolute; }
```

**Javascript**

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("div#logomarca").show();
    $("p#spec").fadeTo(0, 0.00,
        function() { if($.browser.msie) { this.style.removeAttribute('filter'); }; } 
    ); //hide() is not working with fadeIn
    if($.browser.msie) { 
                $("p#spec").css({ 
                "margin-top": "8px",  
                "margin-left": "-165px", 
                display: "none"  
                }); 
            };  
    $("div#logomarca").animate({
        top: "+=50%",
        opacity: 1.00
        }, 2500, 
        function() { if($.browser.msie) { this.style.removeAttribute('filter'); }; } 
        );
    $(this).delay(3200,function(){  
        if($.browser.msie) { $("p#spec").show(); };
$("p#spec").fadeTo(0, 0.00  ); 
        $("p#spec").animate({
            opacity: 1.00,
            top: "+=20"     
            }, 2500,
            function() { if($.browser.msie) { 
                this.style.removeAttribute('filter'); 
                }; }            
            );
        $(this).delay(3500,function(){  
            $("p#spec").fadeTo(800, 0.0);
            $(this).delay(650,function(){  
                $("h1#marca").fadeTo(1500, 0.0);
                });
            });
        });
 });
```

Comment: Can you produce a test case?  In other words, working code which shows the problem?  Also, is the problem with IE6, IE7, or both?

Comment: If you're asking a question about IE, it would be helpful to know what version you're talking about, especially for JS and CSS issues.

Comment: sure... sorry about that. It's IE7. I decided not to work with IE6 anymore

Comment: I was unable to reproduce the bug with the example you provided.  Opera, Firefox, and IE all work fine (except IE has an unrelated bug where it starts at a different location).

Comment: well no problem about the location, that's easy to fix, but can't understand why it's different... here, it works fine with Fx, Opera, webkits, but IE7 is still "shaking" the p#spec content at the end of the animation, just before fading out. It's hard to see but enough to get a client's complaint:(

Comment: Tested once again, and I still cannot reproduce the bug.  See: http://jsbin.com/ozomo (http://jsbin.com/ozomo/edit)

Comment: Also, Firebug reports an error in your Javascript: $(this).delay is not a function.  Not sure if it's JSBin's fault, though.

Comment: uh-oh. sorry again, it's a plugin. Well, may I give you the address where I put all that code so you can see the effect I'm talking about? Here it is: http://www.ysatis.com.br/test_js/test_splash.html Should I do something about the plugin (maybe show you the download location)?

Comment: I saw your test, well, there's only one of the two texts and I'm afraid the problem is about the other one.

Comment: I have looked at your page in IE7.  I see no problems other than the subtitle being on the left instead of under the title.  7.0.6001.18000, both 32-bit and 64-bit.

Comment: Well, maybe then it depends on my PC specific configuration. I'll try tomorrow in another machine, let's see. Thank you so much for the feedback!

Comment: I've tried in two othr PCs, both of them running IE6 (!!!) 
There's a shifting as well but it happens on the <h1>, not on the <p> text. Couldn't test in another IE7 for now. 
I still think there'a something in IE rendering that causes such impredictible, but common behaviour - I wonder what it is?

Answer (score 1):

It would help if you could post a minimized working sample so we can look at the code.

My best guess is that you need to wrap your element with a block-level element (`div` or `p`) and give that element '`position: relative;`' for IE to behave.

Comment: that's already the case: 
<div id="logomarca">
  <h1 id="marca">txt</h1>
  <p id="spec">txt</p>
</div>
where both div,p{position:absolute;}
It happens after the following anim:
$("p#spec").animate({opacity: 1.00,top: "+=20"},2500,and filter removing}; (sorry about format,running out of space here)

Comment: @satinka, You should really add your code to your original question.  I did the best I could for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping in a div with fixed dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

Change the margin to padding and see if that helps. I had a really similar problem recently and that solved it.